# How to retrieve ParseObject from Parse DataBrowser

Tags: android, parsing

i have this code: where i retrieve the courses of a certain student that is loged with the name in "NameCurrentStudent" and then stock the courses in an ArrayList

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Courses");
    query = query.whereEqualTo("Student", NameCurrentStudent);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> courseList, ParseException e) 
        {
            if (e == null) 
            {
                courses.clear();
                for (ParseObject course : courseList) 
                {
                    courses.add(course.getString("NameCourse"));
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.d("Post retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

but when i use debug it skipps query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
anyone know's why ?

Comment: Because you are defining and setting a Callback. this callback is only registered and will be executed when the query runs, and is done. - Checkout: http://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#findInBackground(com.parse.FindCallback)

Comment: the callback would be executed in an other thread, you can check the result by Logging something like the size of the list, or the content, to check the function.

Comment: yeah, but i need to retrieve the list not just one course

Comment: ok, ill give it a try

Comment: sorry, it doesnt seem to work

Comment: This function runs only in the first window of the aplication, so i had to send the list to the second one ...

Comment: so you should get familiar with intents - but when i understand you right, its another question.

Comment: and the problem is solved for now but i have to use this in a more deep class that uses the Notes from the Course which i cant call it again from the main Screen'Class

Comment: I have rezolved the problem but it was tricky, i realized that  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback()  in other classes than the first one (in my case Login screen) it is starting another thread behind my current class whitch is puted in Background so i had to work inside it to force making my implementation. The answer i finded it was to call the class that populates my lists (of Courses and Notes) inside the function  query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() { ... populateList( ArrayList<String> Notes; etc etc }; It isn't pretty but it works.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the answers, looks like Parse doesnt care about answering my question of this simplicity still they dont specify anything of this problem in they're tutorials, -1 to them.

Comment: Answer your own question to help peoples with the same problem - PS: its best pracice ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryP = ParseQuery.getQuery("Courses");
    queryP.whereEqualTo("Student", nameStudent);
    queryP.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> coursesList, ParseException e) 
        {
            ArrayList<String> courses = null;
            if (e == null) 
            {
                courses = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (ParseObject course : coursesList) 
                {
                    String courseName = course.getString("CoursesNameInParseColumn");       
                    courses.add(courseName);
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.d("Post retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            populateCoursesList(courses);
        }
    });
```

Comment: force the function populateCoursesList with the reference courses ArrayList<String>